# How can I test on_failure in celery

Tags: python, unit-testing, celery, celery-task

My celery task has a base class were an `on_failure` method is implemented.

In my test, I patched one of the methods that the task is calling to, to raise an exception but `on_faliure` is never called.

Base class

```
class BaseTask(celery.Task):
    abstract = True 

    def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
        print("error")
```

Task

```
@celery.task(bind=True, base=BaseTask)
def multiple(self, a, b):
    logic.method(a, b)
```

Test

```
@patch('tasks.logic.method')
def test_something(self, mock):
    # arrange
    mock.side_effect = NotImplementedError

    # act
    with self.assertRaises(NotImplementedError):
        multiple(1, 2)
```

When running celery and an exception is raised everything works fine.
`CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER` is activated.

how can I make `on_faliure` run?

Comment: My solution was not to run `multiple` as is but via sync celery

Answer (score 3):

From a [discussion on a issue in celery GitHub](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4778#issuecomment-394401645): `on_failure` test is *"already done on the Celery level (verifying if on_failure is called)"* and *"write a test to test whatever your on_failure does instead"*. You could define a function inside the `on_failure` method and test it, or call `on_failure` like a classmethod:

```
import TestCase
from billiard.einfo import ExceptionInfo

class TestTask(TestCase):
    def test_on_failure(self):
        "Testing on failure method"

        exc = Exception("Test")
        task_id = "test_task_id"
        args = ["argument 1"]
        kwargs = {"key": "value"}
        einfo = ExceptionInfo

        # call on_failure method
        multiple.on_failure(exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo)

        # assert something appened
```

`ExceptionInfo` is the same type of object `celery` uses; `multiple` is your task as you defined it in your question.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate the exception in the `run` method + `task_eager_propagates=False` + `result.get`

`task_eager_propagates=False` - won't raise the exception immediately
`result.get` - assures that task is finished (without that test may be flaky)

```
import celery
import logging


class BaseTask(celery.Task):
    abstract = True

    def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
        logging.error("on_failure called")


class Foo():
    def bar(*args):
        pass


@app.task(base=BaseTask)
def multiple(a, b):
    Foo().bar(a, b)


@override_settings(task_eager_propagates=False)
@mock.patch.object(Foo, 'bar', side_effect=NotImplementedError)
def test_something(mock_, caplog):

    result = multiple.delay(1, 2)

    with pytest.raises(NotImplementedError):
        result.get()

    assert "on_failure called" in  caplog.messages
```